Can I data bind controls in a community toolkit maui popup in a view model?
I'm trying to create a message box that would display varied messages and headers. So what I'm kind of looking for is a way to data bind the displayed label controls in the XAML file.
Here's what I have so far:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ctm:Popup xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:ctm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
           xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:LockAndKeyMaui.ViewModels"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="LockAndKeyMaui.MsgBox"
           CanBeDismissedByTappingOutsideOfPopup="False"
           Color="Blue">

    <VerticalStackLayout>
        <Label 
            Text="Success!"
            Margin="5,5,0,0" FontSize="20"
            FontAttributes="Bold" FontFamily="Arial"
            TextColor="White" x:Name="lblHdr"/>
        <Label 
            Text="Completed Successfully..."
            HorizontalOptions="Center"
            VerticalOptions="Center"
            FontSize="16" FontFamily="Arial"
            TextColor="Yellow" x:Name="lblMsg"/>
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ctm:Popup>

And my view model:
using CommunityToolkit.Maui.Core;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace LockAndKeyMaui.ViewModels
{
    public partial class MsgViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string? msgtxt, hdrtxt;

        public string MsgTxt
        {
            get => msgtxt!;
            set
            {
                msgtxt = value;
                OnPropChg(nameof(MsgTxt));
            }
        }

        public string HdrTxt
        {
            get => hdrtxt!;
            set
            {
                hdrtxt = value;
                OnPropChg(nameof(HdrTxt));
            }
        }

        private readonly IPopupService popupService;

        public MsgViewModel(IPopupService popupService)
        {
            this.popupService = popupService;
        }

        public void DisplayPopup(string ptxt, string phdr = "")
        {
            this.popupService.ShowPopup<MsgViewModel>(onPresenting: vwMod => vwMod.PerformUpdts(ptxt, phdr));
        }

        public void PerformUpdts(string txt, string hdr = "")
        {
            HdrTxt = hdr;
            MsgTxt = txt;
        }


        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;

        private void OnPropChg(string prName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prName));
        }
    }
}

So when I display the popup I would want to do something like this:
DisplayPopup("User Name has been copied.", "Copied");
Task.Delay(2000);
Close();
return;

And somehow bind the two input strings to the label controls. How can I do this?
Also, this DisplayPopup method is written in the MsgViewModel file. How can I access it from a different view model?
